# Meteor app deployment fibers issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, build

I do deploy meteor app on Ubuntu server

```
uname -a Linux ns3001615.ip-37-59-49.eu 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #5 SMP Wed Sep 9 17:24:34 CEST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Server node version: 4.6.2
Server meteor node version: 4.6.2
Server meteor version: 1.4.2.3
Local os: Windows 7
Local node version: 4.6.2
Local Meteor version 1.4.2.3
```

I build meteor app locally and put it to server. Then I unzip tar and run npm install from bundle/programs/server

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/home/fl/preprod/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-11/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/bin/node /home/fl/preprod/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build

/home/fl/preprod/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20
        throw new Error('Missing binary. See message above.');
              ^
Error: Missing binary. See message above.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fl/preprod/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fl/preprod/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

I tried rebuild fibers but no result. I can't see linux-x64-11 in the bin folder

What did I miss? Thx

Comment: I found out that if I start main.js directly from node (not by forever as I did it previously) then it works correctly.